# Cruise Control .Net - Turn off Versioning

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

Every time cruise control performs a build it update the history of each file with a label, i.e. update to version 14, etc.

How can I turn this off so that it does not update the files and just performs the build?

Answer (score 0):

First check if you have a `<labeller>` block somewhere in the config file. If you have, this overwrites the default labeller, which simply distinguishes one build from another.